# change theme color flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

The theme color of my flutter project changed when I implement the dark & light mode. I've tried changing the primary color but still won't work. Is there any solutions?

[image]

Here is the code to my /provider/theme_provider.dart

```
class MyThemes {
  static final darkTheme = ThemeData(
    primaryColor: Color(0xFF2481CF),
  );
}
```

And the code in my /lib/Home.dart where I want to change the theme color:

```
               Container(
                      // color: Colors.white,
                      height: 420,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 30),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        children: <Widget>[
                        TextField(
                          autofocus:true,
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                            labelText: 'Enter your name',
                          ),
                        ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 15,
                          ),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                            children: [
                              ElevatedButton(
                                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                    // primary: Colors.white,
                                    elevation: 0
                                ),
                                child: const Text(
                                  'Cancel',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black
                                  ),),
                                onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                              ),
                              ElevatedButton(
                                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                    // primary: Colors.white,
                                    elevation: 0
                                ),
                                child: const Text(
                                  'Save',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black
                                  ),),
                                onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
```

Comment: without code samples we can't correct your code :-D

Comment: i've updated my questions @Raegtime

Answer (score 0):

```
////Create a theme provider class and you can change the theme through this class hope this will work for you, Thanks 
   
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:traveling/helpers/AppColors.dart';
    class ThemeProvider extends ChangeNotifier{
      ThemeMode themeMode = ThemeMode.light;
      bool get isLightMode => themeMode == ThemeMode.light;
      void toggleTheme(bool isOn){
        themeMode = isOn?ThemeMode.light:ThemeMode.dark;
        notifyListeners();
      }
    }
    
    class MyTheme {
      static final darkTheme = ThemeData(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade900,
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.dark(),
        primaryColor: AppColors.white,
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: AppColors.white),
          primaryColorLight: Color(0xff1F2C34),
        cardTheme: CardTheme(color: Color(0xff262626),),
        textTheme: TextTheme(
          headline1:TextStyle( color:AppColors.white,),
            headline2: TextStyle( color:Color(0xff262626),),
            caption: TextStyle(color: AppColors.white)
        )
      );
      static final lightTheme = ThemeData(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
          primaryColor: AppColors.hotelListDarkBlue,
          cardTheme: CardTheme(color: Colors.grey[200],),
          primaryColorLight: AppColors.baseLightBlueColor,
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(),
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(
          color: AppColors.baseLightBlueColor,
        ),
          textTheme: TextTheme(
            headline1: TextStyle(color: AppColors.hotelListDarkBlue,),
              headline2: TextStyle( color:AppColors.white,),
              caption: TextStyle(color: AppColors.hotelListDarkBlue,
              )
          )
      );
    }
///I also create a switch button to st the theme
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:traveling/Theme/Theme.dart';
import 'package:traveling/helpers/AppColors.dart';

class ChangeThemeButtonWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const ChangeThemeButtonWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  ///Creating a switch button to change the theme and it will be changed after clicking on switch left to right.

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final themeProvider = Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context);
    return Switch.adaptive(
      activeColor: AppColors.baseLightBlueColor,
      activeTrackColor: AppColors.profiePicBackground,
      inactiveTrackColor: AppColors.profiePicBackground,
      inactiveThumbColor: AppColors.white,
      dragStartBehavior: DragStartBehavior.start,
        value: themeProvider.isLightMode,
      onChanged: (value){
          /*final provider = Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context,listen: false);
          provider.toggleTheme(value);*/
      },

    );
  }
}


//you can call the theme object like this  Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor, i am sharing few line of code of Setting Page
 Column(
          children: [
            CustomWidgets.searchField(context: context),
            /// StickyGroupedListView used for creating list of expense report
            /// where we show status onHold,Pending,And other expense data
             ListTile(
            onTap: (){
            },
            title: Text("Notification",style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1!.color),),
            leading: Icon(MdiIcons.bellRing,color: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color,),
            trailing: Icon(MdiIcons.chevronRight,color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
          ),
```